# Flex table like component

Tags: apache-flex

Is there are component in Flex where we can display the data in table format.

http://code.google.com/p/flex-table/

I did not like the look and feel, any other components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "data in table format" seems to point to [`DataGrid`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html).

If that's not what you have in mind, can you better explain why that, `Grid`, and `flex-table` don't meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

The Grid component in the Flex SDK does tabular layout. Otherwise, I think you've answered your own question. If you try the flex-table, let us know how well it works for you.

Comment: It worked well for me, i need to create rows and columns... is it possible in flex datagrid..